Contains function behaves weird in Oracle 19c DB
I tried the below given script and I got no result for SELECT  SCORE(1), id, name FROM mytxts WHERE CONTAINS(name, 'MS', 1) > 0 ;, whereas all other queries work as expected.
I couldn't find any fix to get the result of the above query. Is Oracle completely avoiding MS ? :-) Just kidding.
I tried the below in my 19c Oracle DB.
CREATE TABLE mytxts (id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR2(200));

INSERT INTO mytxts VALUES(1, '<HTML>California is a state in the US.</HTML>');
INSERT INTO mytxts VALUES(2, '<HTML>Paris is a city in France.</HTML>');
INSERT INTO mytxts VALUES(3, '<HTML>France is in Europe.</HTML>');
INSERT INTO mytxts VALUES(4, '<HTML>MS</HTML>');
INSERT INTO mytxts VALUES(5, '<HTML>MS1</HTML>');
INSERT INTO mytxts VALUES(6, '<HTML>MSA</HTML>');
INSERT INTO mytxts VALUES(7, '<HTML>MS2</HTML>');
INSERT INTO mytxts VALUES(8, '<HTML> MS </HTML>');
INSERT INTO mytxts VALUES(9, '<HTML>ms</HTML>');
INSERT INTO mytxts VALUES(10, '<HTML>ms1</HTML>');
INSERT INTO mytxts VALUES(11, '<HTML>msa</HTML>');
INSERT INTO mytxts VALUES(12, '<HTML>Paris is a city in France</HTML>');
INSERT INTO mytxts VALUES(13, '<HTML>France</HTML>');
INSERT INTO mytxts VALUES(14, '<HTML>MS is a name</HTML>');
INSERT INTO mytxts VALUES (15, '<HTML> MSD is a Indian Cricket Player.</HTML>') ;
INSERT INTO mytxts VALUES (16, '<HTML> MS was found by Bill Gates.</HTML>') ;
INSERT INTO mytxts VALUES (17, '<HTML> KS is my name.</HTML>') ;
INSERT INTO mytxts VALUES (18, '<HTML> KS is MS</HTML>') ;
INSERT INTO mytxts VALUES (19, '<HTML> KS is not MS. </HTML>') ;

COMMIT ;

DROP INDEX IDX_MYTXTS ;

CREATE INDEX idx_mytxts ON mytxts (name)
INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT PARAMETERS
('FILTER CTXSYS.NULL_FILTER SECTION GROUP CTXSYS.HTML_SECTION_GROUP');

COLUMN name FORMAT a40;

SELECT * FROM MYTXTS ORDER BY ID  desc;

SELECT SCORE(1), id, name FROM mytxts WHERE CONTAINS(name, 'France', 1) > 0;

SELECT  SCORE(1), id, name FROM mytxts WHERE CONTAINS(name, 'KS', 1) > 0 ;

--  No results for this query.
SELECT  SCORE(1), id, name FROM mytxts WHERE CONTAINS(name, 'MS', 1) > 0 ;



Is Oracle completely avoiding MS ? :-)

Yes, but as "Ms" (like "Miss"/"Mrs"), not because of Microsoft, if that's what you were hinting at.
The word "Ms" appears in the English default stoplist, which means that it is not indexed.
You could remove "Ms" from the default stoplist, but you probably want to create your own, with:
BEGIN
  CTX_DDL.CREATE_STOPLIST('mystoplist');
END;
/

and add any words you do want to exclude to that. You can then specifythe stoplist in your create index"
CREATE INDEX idx_mytxts ON mytxts (name)
  INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT
  PARAMETERS ('FILTER CTXSYS.NULL_FILTER SECTION GROUP CTXSYS.HTML_SECTION_GROUP STOPLIST mystoplist');

(Unfortunately, CTX_DDL is not available in db<>fiddle, so I can't show it working...)

Hi  Alex ,
That's awesome.

I'll change the direction towards CTX_DDL and do some research on stoplist.
Thank You again
